# Indexed key vs indexed separate columns, which one is faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

In MYSQL, from a pure performance perspective, if I have a table with large amount of data with 10/1 read/write ratio.  is it faster in read/write performance to have 4 search criteria in separate columns and all indexed or have them combined in to one single string acting as a key and store in one indexed column  ?

e.g. say this table with 5 columns, first name, last name, sex, country and file where the first four columns will ALWAYS be given as a part of search parameters in a search or have a table with two columns, key and file.  where the value of key can be john-smith-male-australia ??

I don't quite get the pros and cons. the point I try to stress is the fact that all parameters will be given.in a search.

Comment: depends somewhat on the query workload being seen...and the selectivity of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the fact that all parameters will be given.in a search.

For that specific case, if it is a design possibility to mash the 4 columns into a fifth (varchar) and index that, then go for it.  It flattens the index tree so it does not need to go 3 branches deep to the leaf level.  It also allows very quick binary partitionining to get to the data wanted, **as long as** the mashing is **exactly** in the `order of selectivity`.

Comment: You'll also need an extra constraint and some triggers to make sure "the mash" is always equal to the original columns.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Get the queries first, then work back from that because these are your test cases.  From those, you have to test if composite indexes, separate indexes, or one single composite index work best for the data and what you want to retrieve.  We can suggested informed opinions, but nothing more without access to the entirety of your data and the queries you'd be using.

Answer (score 0):

From my [sql indexing tutorial](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

> Always aim to index the original data.
>   That is often the most useful
>   information you can put into an index.

It is essentially the same if you concatenate the columns on your own, or if you let the DB do it. It's just less work, less error prone and less awkward if you let the DB do it.

And, on top of that, if you index the original data, you can also use it as **covering index**, that can give you a **huge** performance benefit if you are **querying the indexed columns only**.